# Multiple image resize before the upload with a temp folder

Tags: php, html, sql, database, image

i need help for this, i spend all my day for try to resize a picture in PHP :(((.

I find a good subject [Resize the image-file before uploading; Could we overwrite the temp file & upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034263/resize-the-image-file-before-uploading-could-we-overwrite-the-temp-file-uploa)

BUT, when i try to use for me my add.php return me a little white square like this : [image]

and my image is not resized in my folder.

I propably forget to change something in the code or failed to use but, i really need help Thanks you.

```
require_once('../connexion.php');

extract($_POST);

// This will count total images selected.
$TotalImage = count($_FILES['image']['name']);
$domaine   = isset($_POST['domaine']) ? $_POST['domaine'] : null;

for($i = 0;$i<$TotalImage;$i++)
{ 
    $tempFile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
    $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($image_name, '.'), 1));
    $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/AprimeWeb/img/sliders/'.$domaine .'/'.$image_name;

    $image_properties = getimagesize($tempFile);
    $image_width = $image_properties[0];
    $image_height = $image_properties[1];
    $percent = 0.5; //Percentage by which the image is going to be resized

    $newWidth = $image_width * $percent;
    $newHeight = $image_height * $percent;

    if ($ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "jpg") {
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        $thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($tempFile);
    } elseif ($ext == "png") {
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        $thumb = imagecreatefrompng($tempFile);
    }

    $modifiedFile = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    imagecopyresampled(
        $modifiedFile,
        $thumb, 
        0, 
        0,
        0, 
        0,
        $new_width, 
        $new_height, 
        $width,
        $height
    );

      if(imagejpeg($tempFile, $target_path))
      {
         $sql = "INSERT INTO images SET name = '$image_name', domaine = '$domaine'" ;
            $return['success'] = $connexion->exec($sql);
            echo json_encode($return);
      }
      header('Location: ../admin_sliders.php');
}
```

EDIT ANSWER---------------------------------------------------------------

The good way was provide by @keziah but he do a little bit mistake, for make the code work you need to add a `for` condition with a `count($_FILES['image']['name']);` and a `[$i]` at the end of each `$_FILES['image']['*****']`

Like this

```
    <?php
// Image config

require_once('../connexion.php');

$max_image_size = 500;            //Maximum image size (height and width) (pixels)
$destination_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/AprimeWeb/img/sliders/'.$_POST['domaine'] .'/'; //upload directory ends with /
$jpeg_quality = 90;               // jpeg quality (percent)
$domaine   = isset($_POST['domaine']) ? $_POST['domaine'] : null;
$TotalImage = count($_FILES['image']['name']); //give the number of image you upload
extract($_POST);


for($i = 0;$i<$TotalImage;$i++){
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'][$i])) {
    // check $_FILES['image'] not empty
    if (!isset($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
        die('Image file is Missing!');

    }

    // uploaded file info
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];     //file name
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];     //file size
    $image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]; //file temp
    $image_size_info = getimagesize($image_temp); //get image size

    if ($image_size_info) {
        $image_width = $image_size_info[0];     //image width
        $image_height = $image_size_info[1];    //image height
        $image_type = $image_size_info['mime']; //image type
    } else {
        die("Make sure image file is valid!");
    }

    // creates new image from given file 
    // also, it validates the accepted image format
    switch ($image_type) {
        case 'image/png':
            $image_res = imagecreatefrompng($image_temp);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $image_res = imagecreatefromgif($image_temp);
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
            $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp);
            break;
        default:
            $image_res = false;
    }

    if ($image_res) {
      var_dump($image_res);
        //Get file extension and name to construct new file name 
        $image_info = pathinfo($image_name);
        $image_extension = strtolower($image_info["extension"]); //image extension
        $image_name_only = strtolower($image_info["filename"]); //file name only, no extension
        //create a random name for new image (Eg: fileName_293749.jpg) ;
        $new_file_name = $image_name_only . '_' . rand(0, 99999) . '.' . $image_extension;

        //folder path to save resized images and thumbnails
        $image_save_folder = $destination_folder . $new_file_name;

        // proportionally resize image
        if (normal_resize_image($image_res, $image_save_folder, $image_type, $max_image_size, $image_width, $image_height, $jpeg_quality)) {

            /* Now, output image to user's browser or store information in the database */

            $sql = "INSERT INTO images SET name = '$new_file_name', domaine = '$domaine'" ;
            $return['success'] = $connexion->exec($sql);
            echo json_encode($return);
        }

        imagedestroy($image_res); //freeup memory
    }
    else {
        die('Invalid image format.');
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The `normal_resize_image()`

**Params**

- Source       - `imagecreatefrom*($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);` - `*` means any image format
- Destination  - `uploads/` - your uploads directory
- Image type   - `getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])['mime']` - image mime type
- Max size     - your custom image size would be `200, 400, 500` pixels
- Image width  - `getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])[0]` - image width
- Image height - `getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])[1]` - image height
- Quality      - The JPEG quality would be `80, 90, 100` percent

Image resizer

```
<?php
function normal_resize_image($source, $destination, $image_type, $max_size, $image_width, $image_height, $quality) {

    if ($image_width <= 0 || $image_height <= 0) {
        return false;
    } //return false if nothing to resize
    //do not resize if image is smaller than max size
    if ($image_width <= $max_size && $image_height <= $max_size) {
        if (save_image($source, $destination, $image_type, $quality)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Construct a proportional size of new image
    $image_scale = min($max_size / $image_width, $max_size / $image_height);
    $new_width = ceil($image_scale * $image_width);
    $new_height = ceil($image_scale * $image_height);

    $new_canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height); //Create a new true color image
    //Copy and resize part of an image with resampling
    if (imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height)) {
        save_image($new_canvas, $destination, $image_type, $quality); //save resized image
    }

    return true;
}
?>
```

#### The `save_image()`

**Params**

- Source      - your image source (same as above)
- Destination - uploads folder/directory (same as above)
- Image type  - image mime type (same as above)
- Quality     - JPEG quality (same as above)

Saves image to resource file

```
<?php
function save_image($source, $destination, $image_type, $quality) {
    switch (strtolower($image_type)) {//determine mime type
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($source, $destination);
            return true; //save png file
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            imagejpeg($source, $destination, $quality);
            return true; //save jpeg file
            break;
        default: return false;
    }
}
```

#### Sample Usage

```
<?php
// Image config
$max_image_size = 500;            //Maximum image size (height and width) (pixels)
$destination_folder = 'uploads/'; //upload directory ends with /
$jpeg_quality = 90;               // jpeg quality (percent)

if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {

    // check $_FILES['image'] not empty
    if (!isset($_FILES['image']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        die('Image file is Missing!');
    }

    // uploaded file info
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];     //file name
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];     //file size
    $image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; //file temp

    $image_size_info = getimagesize($image_temp); //get image size

    if ($image_size_info) {
        $image_width = $image_size_info[0];     //image width
        $image_height = $image_size_info[1];    //image height
        $image_type = $image_size_info['mime']; //image type
    } else {
        die("Make sure image file is valid!");
    }

    // creates new image from given file 
    // also, it validates the accepted image format
    switch ($image_type) {
        case 'image/png':
            $image_res = imagecreatefrompng($image_temp);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $image_res = imagecreatefromgif($image_temp);
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
            $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp);
            break;
        default:
            $image_res = false;
    }

    if ($image_res) {
        //Get file extension and name to construct new file name 
        $image_info = pathinfo($image_name);
        $image_extension = strtolower($image_info["extension"]); //image extension
        $image_name_only = strtolower($image_info["filename"]); //file name only, no extension
        //create a random name for new image (Eg: fileName_293749.jpg) ;
        $new_file_name = $image_name_only . '_' . rand(0, 99999) . '.' . $image_extension;

        //folder path to save resized images and thumbnails
        $image_save_folder = $destination_folder . $new_file_name;

        // proportionally resize image
        if (normal_resize_image($image_res, $image_save_folder, $image_type, $max_image_size, $image_width, $image_height, $jpeg_quality)) {

            /* Now, output image to user's browser or store information in the database */
            echo '<div align="center">';
            echo '<img src="uploads/' . $new_file_name . '" alt="Resized Image">';
            echo '</div>';

            // COde to store the image into database
        }

        imagedestroy($image_res); //freeup memory
    }
    else {
        die('Invalid image format.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, but can you tell me how to use that ?